# fundamental C quicksort

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm struggling with quicksort in Knking example.

```
int split(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int part_element = a[low];
    
    for(;;)
    {
        while(low < high && part_element <= a[high])
            high--;
        if(low >= high)
            break;
        a[low++] = a[high];
        
        while(low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
            low++;
        if(low >= high)
            break;
        a[high--] = a[low];
        }
    
    a[high] = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

I wonder why the condition `if(low >= high)` has `>`.
evertime high gets smaller and low gets bigger they sometime be the same.
why the book included the `>` in the condition?
I think it is enough with `if(low == high)`.

In which situation `low` can be bigger than `high`?

Comment: Are the lines `if(low > high)` and `printf("This is equal\n");` lines you added? If so, you should say that when you ask a question, so people know what was in the original code. When referring to the work of other people, you should also give a complete citation so other people can find it—author, title, date, publisher, and so on—and a URL if available. It appears the source code you refer to may be [here](http://www.knking.com/books/c2/programs/qsort.c).

Comment: I forgot to erase code I added.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome aboard. And congratulations on a  good question (upvote). It is perfectly fine on this site, but you might also want to be aware of our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.  Post here if the code does not work, post there if it works, but you want critique and advice on improving it. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true the code in `split` cannot cause `high` to become less than `low`, using `>=` is useful because:

- The routine may be called with `high` already less than `low`. For example, if a program filters a list of some things, and ends up with zero things<sup>1</sup> and then tries to sort the empty list using `quicksort`, it will call it with `low` = 0 and `high` = −1.<sup>2</sup> When this happens, we want to `split` to exit without making any modifications.
- Using `>=` generally has the same performance as `==`; the processor does not do any extra work for `>=`. Commonly, `int` values are compared with a single instruction that completely determines the relationship (`<`, `=`, or `>`, sometimes with other results as well) and reports them in flags or a result register. Then another instruction branches based on the results.
- It is good practice to guard against bugs. In case some mistake in the source code causes `high` to become less than `low`, we might prefer the routine to exit before doing any further damage. (Which decisions to make in such cases are generally sensitive to the situation.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> For example, consider a real estate search engine for which a user has requested information about houses for sale in a certain town. The software might retrieve all such houses from a database. Then it might apply the user’s filters, such as eliminating all houses except those that have three bedrooms and are less than a certain price. The result of those filters might be an empty list.

<sup>2</sup> In [the original code](http://www.knking.com/books/c2/programs/qsort.c), `quicksort` contains its own test that prevents it from calling `split` with `low` greater than `high`, so this reason does not apply with this particular calling code. Nonetheless, it is a good design for `split` to behave well when called with `low` greater than `high`.